# write text from comand line into Hadoop

Tags: file, shell, unix, hadoop, hdfs

Is it possible to write text from the command line into Hadoop?

Trying to do something similar to the unix write/append to file command.

```
echo "hello world" > hello_world.txt
```

In Hadoop land I would expect this to work, but the commands do not.

```
hadoop fs -appendToFile "foo bar" /dir/hadoop/hello_world.txt

hadoop fs -put "hello world" /dir/hadoop/hello_world.txt
```

Comment: expect this to work, but didn't work for you ? can you clarify your question?

Comment: so what is the error ?

Comment: do you still have issues using -appendToFile?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Hadoop document states [appendToFile](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#appendToFile) and [put](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#put) can read `stdin`

`echo "hello world" | hadoop fs -appendToFile - /dir/hadoop/hello_world.txt`

`echo "hello world" | hadoop fs -put - /dir/hadoop/hello_world.txt`